# python for loop reiterate

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a really simple python problem but it does not seem that simple. I am performing a database query however it boils down to the principle below.

```
fruits = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"]
for x in fruits:
    print(x)
    fruits = ["1", "2", "3"]
    print(fruits)
```

How do I get x to change to the new values?

Current output for x is "apple", "banana", "cherry" however after I change fruit I would like "apple", "1", "2", "3"

Comment: what do you mean by "get x to change to the new values" ? What is the excepted output ?

Comment: You cannot, and you really don't want to.  If you think you do, then you probably have a better approach that you're not seeing.  What's the real question?

Comment: @cdrom My understanding of the question is that OP wants to change the values that are being iterated over, and he's expecting something like "apple", "1", "2", "3" or "apple", "2", "3".

Comment: Like @cdrom said, what is your desired output ?

Comment: edited the question for the desired output

Comment: But you `print(x)` once before changing the `fruits` variable.  So you'll have "apple" printed either way.  What do you want it to print out specifically?

Comment: Ok, that's better, but what I'm not understanding is why you are attempting to structure your list printing in this manner.  What's actual problem are you trying to solve?  This smells like an XY problem.  You want to solve X, you think you can do it using Y, so you ask about Y.  But you can get better answers if you just ask about X.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I undestand your question correctly, then you DON'T change collection while you iterate through it.
What you can do is to iterate over range of indexes and then you can change collection. Like:

```py
fruits = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"]
for i in range(len(fruits)):
    print(fruits[i])
    fruits = ["1", "2", "3"]
    print(fruits)
```

But be careful with index out of range if your `fruits` length changes. The safest way would be to use `while` loop:

```
fruits = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"]
i = 0;
while i < len(fruits):
    print(fruits[i])
    fruits = ["1", "2", "3"]
    print(fruits)
    i += 1
```

If you want to completely reset iterations in same loop, which is very strange scenario, but you can do:

```
fruits = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"]
i = 0
while i < len(fruits):
    print(fruits[i])
    newFruits = ["1", "2", "3"]
    if newFruits != fruits:
        i = -1
        fruits = newFruits
    print(fruits)
    i += 1
```

Mind that this code is inefficient, cause:

1. You assign new array on each iteration, which can cause a memory leak.
2. Comparing arrays is O(n) complexity operation.

For better code, more information about the problem is needed.

Comment: Thanks the second part of your answer is what I was looking for

Comment: Unfortunately, if you reread the post, he updated it, such that changing the list should restart iteration.  So this approach won't easily work.

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity, updated, although not very efficient I agree.

Comment: It's the only reasonable way really to approach this problem how he wants.  I still don't know why he thinks he wants to do this though.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear, but to move your first print statements from `"apple", "banana", "cherry"` to `"1", "2", "3"` you can do:

```
fruits = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"]
for x in fruits:
    print(x)
fruits = ["1", "2", "3"]
for x in fruits:
    print(x)
```